# how to rip several minutes of dvd with subtitles - using VLC

Tags: windows-7, dvd, vlc-media-player, ripping, handbrake

Title says it all...I want to rip several minutes of a DVD movie - *with* subtitles - using VLC (or Handbrake).  How can I do this?  OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a video tutorial on how to do this [here](http://youtube.jimmyr.com/tutorials/sdQKtxto7C4.php) for a slightly older version of VLC but it is still useful.

Some changes from the video tutorial:

Stream and save has been renamed to Convert/Save (which can be found under the Media menu)

VLC has pre-created profiles for audio and video encoding. you can choose one of those or create your own.

In order to include the subtitles, you will have to figure out which "subtitle track" is associated with a particular subtitle language in the convert/save screen for dvd's. You can do that with trial and error with regular playback and then choose convert/save when you found the options you'd like to use. The default subtitle track is -1 which seems to indicate no subtitle.

Make sure to check the "No DVD Menus" check box. You can start from a particular title and track, though I would recommend letting it process through the end and then cutting out the desired scene with something like VirtualDub or windows movie maker. Some codecs require some post processing attention which does not seem to work properly if you stop VLC's process prematurely.